# Integrate Asana into Microsoft CRM platforms

Tags: crm, asana

Asana looks like it is easy to use and extremely fast.

My company currently uses the slow and terrible Microsoft CRM, would it be possible to use Asana as the front end and send the inputted data to the MS CRM database?

I understand that a MS API is most likely needed as well, however does Asana have the capabilities?

Comment: I know this isn't what you asked for, but MS CRM is an enterprise-scale platform used by large multi-nationals. If you are finding it slow, perhaps the issue is your installation/infrastructure? Have you attempted to address these issues?

Comment: I havent't attempted to fix the issues, Im in sales within my organization but they know my concerns.  It seems though many IT people dont like being told that their setup is slow or not very efficient.  When I saw Asana it looks like it could be a viable solution and I was thinking about making a suggestion to my IT team about other options.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, it's possible to do this, both products have the capability to do what you describe. Asana's API is pretty new though, so you might have some initial limitations; but based on what I suspect you'd want to do, it should be adequate.

But unless you have an incredibly nimble and forward thinking IT group, I don't imagine they would want to build or support this. And if they were nimble and forward thinking, you probably wouldn't be using Microsoft CRM (or at least it wouldn't be slow).